# How to fix Manage Categories error after recovering database

Tags: magento-1.9, category

**Background:**
Dear community, Im experiencing this problem with this Magento 1.9 installation. I have recovered the database from a Magento 1.9 site that was hacked.

My procedure was to scan the database for malware, deleted all users and re-created admin, then connect with a fresh Magento installation.

Magento opened, all the products load.

**Problem:**
I log in the backend and when I try to open **Catalog / Manage Categories**, I get a error message:

*There has been an error processing your request*

The front end, loads perfectly, the categories load and show the content perfectly.

**Checking var/report** the file with the same number of the error message reads:

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:89:"Source model "ThemeConfig/catcolumncount" not found for attribute "products_column_count"";i:1;s:3951:"#0 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(44422): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "T...')
#1 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(2612): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(1987): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(28609): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(1987): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(28609): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#11 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(1987): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(28609): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(28625): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(28392): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(28358): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(28363): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(14198): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(14123): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#21 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#22 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(14272): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#23 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(18750): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(18280): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/includes/src/__default.php(21176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /home/website/public_html/magentoinstallation/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:83:"/magentoinstallation/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/af6c2728f756aa6b1a17cea38c9e6ffe/";s:11:"script_name";s:16:"/jamdx/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I have tried different things like:

- flushing the cache
- compiling

**My questions:**

What else do you think can be the issue?

Possible cause of the problem: I suspect it that the problem could be caused by changing the theme?

**Update**

I have solved the problem by acquiring the theme of the site in its latest version, then re-installed in a brand new Magento installation and all worked perfectly using the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 3rd party module installed that is not working.

Have a look why that module is not working.

**Reason of error:**

This 3rdParty Module installed a new Category Attribute, and attached to it a backend_model of ThemeConfig/catcolumncount (this will now be in your database)

Since that model cannot be located (most likely because that module is not working/installed) the display of that attribute fails.

Comment: Thanks  @Arjun , this is of great help. How can I identify the module that is missing? is this information in the error report log? thank you.

Comment: I think ThemeConfig. Otherwise you need to find yourself by disabling one by one.

Comment: I have solved the problem by acquiring the theme of the site in its latest version, then re-installed in a brand new magento installation and all worked perfectly using the same database. thanks for your help.

Comment: ok. You can edit my answer as per work done by you and then upvote or tick answer so that it may help some one in futher. If you wish 2.